# Toggling Active Class with Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a list of buttons and I would like to toggle the active class but remove the active class from all other buttons in the list. At the moment, I have the active class toggling, but when clicking another button, the other buttons are remaining active.

**UPDATED:** Thanks to the help of @skirtle, I was able to solve my problem.

```
  <li class="tc-product-form__color"
    @click="colorToggle"
    :class="{ 'tc-product-form__color--selected' : currentColor === color }">
    <button role="button" type="button"
      :data-color="color" :data-title="name"
      class="tc-product-form__color-btn js-product-swatch border border-solid"
      :style="backgroundStyle">
    </button>
  </li>
```

This is my component.

```
export default{
    props: ['swatch', 'currentColor'],
    computed: {
    backgroundStyle () {
      if (this.swatch.background.includes('url')) {
        return `backgroundImage: ${this.swatch.background}`
      } else {
        return `backgroundColor: ${this.swatch.background}`
      }
    },
    color () {
      return this.swatch.color
    },
    name () {
      return this.swatch.name
    }   
    },
    methods: {
      colorToggle () {
        this.$emit('change-color', this.color)
      }
    }           
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w37vLL68/158/ is precisely what I'm looking for however, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong to not be able to accomplish the result. Any input would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to be sure from the code you've posted but it looks like the problem is that each swatch/button component has its own value for `currentColor`. To get the radio-button behaviour you want you'd need to have a single `currentColor` property shared between them.

You'd achieve that by having the property owned by the parent component and then passing it down using a prop. The swatch/button component would then fire an event when clicked to update the parent.

A bit like this:

```js
const swatch = {
  template: `
    <li class="tc-product-form__color"
      @click="colorToggle"
      :class="{ 'tc-product-form__color--selected' : currentColor === color }">
      <button role="button" type="button"
        :data-color="color" :data-title="name"
        class="tc-product-form__color-btn js-product-swatch border border-solid"
        :style="backgroundStyle">
      </button>
    </li>
  `,
  
  props: ['swatch', 'currentColor'],
  
  computed: {
    backgroundStyle () {
      if (this.swatch.background.includes('url')) {
        return `backgroundImage: ${this.swatch.background}`
      } else {
        return `backgroundColor: ${this.swatch.background}`
      }
    },
    color () {
      return this.swatch.color
    },
    name () {
      return this.swatch.name
    },
    needsBorder: function() {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    colorToggle () {
      this.$emit('change-color', this.color)
    }           
  }
}


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    swatch
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      currentColor: null,
      swatches: [
        {name: 'Red', color: '#f00', background: '#f77'},
        {name: 'Green', color: '#0f0', background: '#7f7'},
        {name: 'Blue', color: '#00f', background: '#77f'}
      ]
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    onChangeColor (color) {
      this.currentColor = color
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tc-product-form__color {
  list-style: none;
}

.tc-product-form__color-btn {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.tc-product-form__color--selected {
  background: #fdd;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <swatch
      v-for="swatch in swatches"
      :key="swatch.color"
      :swatch="swatch"
      :current-color="currentColor"
      @change-color="onChangeColor"
    ></swatch>
  </ul>
</div>
```

A couple of other notes:

1. Avoid using `this` in templates. I've changed `this.currentColor` to `currentColor`.
2. The properties `color` and `name` should be computed properties. Copying values from the props into `data` is generally unnecessary and often harmful as the values won't update if the props change. In some cases that is desirable behaviour but generally it isn't.

I've tried to leave most of the rest of your code intact so you can see what I've done. The key bits to focus on are the `current-color` prop and the `change-color` event.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly the help I needed even more so, I appreciate the feedback you've included at the bottom. I kept most of your input but altered it slightly for the context of the project, for instance there was already a swatch object. I've updated my work above for reference.